# Database recommendation for custom fields

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I'm building a project which is essentially a CRM for a specific industry. A new requirement has come up which is the client wants to add custom fields to a record type (customer, product etc) and search on those fields, they could be numeric or text. The system is currently built using Laravel and MySQL. I'm wondering if using a JSON column for the custom fields would suffice and what the performance would be like or if I should take the decision early and move to something like Mongo (or other recommendation). Has anyone used JSON fields in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used JSON columns for similar requirements, and that worked out well. That said id might not work for you. Don't know all of the requirements but to move database-layer might be overkill? Can't you seed the database with a bunch of data and just do JSON-lookup tests?

Quick search shows that the performance will still be worse than an indexed lookup ([Is the MySQL JSON data type bad for performance for data retrieval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655312/is-the-mysql-json-data-type-bad-for-performance-for-data-retrieval)).

If you decide to use a JSON-column Laravel has some good ways to search in the JSON columns like: [Search in Json column with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641403/search-in-json-column-with-laravel)